# XMLHttpRequest Getting old values

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to read a file with XMLHttpRequest, get its content and add it to a chart from chart.js.

```
function loadFile() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'file.txt');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      val = xhr.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

file.txt :

```
123
```

I have a button, when I click on it it adds `val` to an array (for my chart).It works, but `val` does not changes when the file is getting changed by the server. So it keeps adding '123' while the content of `file.txt` has changed.

Comment: have you tried check the cache? Like: Press CTRL + F5 before fire another request. Or add  `xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");`

Comment: Thank you, I added `xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");` and called my `loadFile()` when I press my button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is in comment from Paulo Diogo:

> have you tried check the cache? Like: Press CTRL + F5 before fire another request. Or add xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");

I added `xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");` in my button click.